# I changed the IP address on my router and now can't access the web interface

Tags: router, ip, ip-address

I changed the IP address on my bt home hub 5 router from 192.168.1.254 to 192.168.0.254 because I was trying to connect to an IP camera - big mistake.  Now I can connect to the router but there is no internet available and I can't get the web interface to put it back the way it was.  I've tried resetting the router but this doesn't seem to do anything.  Can anyone help? Ta

Comment: What do you mean by reset, [did you press the little red dot with a pen for 20 seconds?](http://bt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/11386/~/how-do-i-reset-my-bt-home-hub-to-its-factory-settings%3F)

Comment: Just connect to `192.168.0.254` and change it back.

Comment: You write " Now I can connect to the router but there is no internet available and I can't get the web interface to put it back the way it was"  <----- What on earth does that mean. You write that you CAN connect to the router, but CAN'T access the web interface. Well, how do you know you can connect to the router. What do you mean when you say you "can connect to the router"?!

Answer (score 3):

I've done this successfully. You need to move your machines from 192.168.1.* into the 192.168.0.* subnet. If they are all on DHCP you can reboot, but it is a lot quicker and easier on Windows to use the connection repair function, or from CMD:

```
ipconfig [/all]                # to identify the interface name
ipconfig {interface} /release  # to clear the current IP address
ipconfig {interface} /renew    # to assign a new IP address from DHCP
ipconfig [/all]                # to check the new IP
```

On Ubuntu, you can simply disconnect and reconnect the interface.

If the interface has been set manually, you will need to change the assigned IP and gateway within the interface's TCP/IP properties.

Once a machine is in the new subnet you can then access the router again through 192.168.0.254.

It should take only a couple of minutes.

Comment: What should take a couple of minutes? waiting for ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew takes max 3 seconds each

Comment: @barlop - I was thinking of the whole job: logging in, running the commands and checking connectivity afterwards, on possibly several machines in different locations.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware factory reset of the router is a fundamental procedure and, at the same time, is very easy. It is recommended to be sure it is doable until you stuck with other issues.

The procedure is described clearly in your router Manual. It requires you to follow the instruction step by step exactly. Because the process is capricious. User is supposed to be holding button down in some specific time period, and the process may rely on some particular duration (all as it is in instruction).

After power cycle you should be able to access its web server with the login and password as they are described in the Manual by default.

Answer (score -1):

The PC is probably retaining now-outdated configuration information. Metaphorically, you have just sawn through the tree branch you were sitting on.

Usually when your PC boots up it gets some information from the router, which also acts as a DHCP (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol) server. One of the pieces of information it acquires is the address of its "default router" - the IP address to which non-local packets should be forwarded. This is usually the router itself, which takes care of forwarding non-local traffic to your IP service provider.

The PC does not know you have reconfigured the router, and so will still be sending traffic to the router's old IP address. That address is no longer responding since your change to the router's address has put it on another IP network.

You should re-configure the PC's IP default router address and perhaps other IP configuration settings to put it on the new network. There have been many excellent suggestions about how to do this.

Comment: -1 rebooting a computer to get a new IP is overkill. see afh's answer

Comment: Also this won't work if the adress' lease time hasn't expired.

Comment: @barlop: Not knowing the level of sophistication of the questioner (though lack of IP knowledge suggests it isn't high) I proposed the easiest fix. Hay to be downvoted for that if it offends your sensibilities.

Comment: @arielnmz You appear to be suggesting that a DHCP server will continue to serve an invalid IP address as the default route? Seems unlikely to me. It's very unlikely to serve anything but its own current internal IP as DNS server and default router, and would have to be pretty dumb to serve up now-invalid cached addresses from a now-foreign network.

Comment: Just note on your answer that the dhcp information is not always renewed at boot time, for instance, my machines only renew dhcp information automatically when the lease time expires, no matter if I reboot the computer. And update your answer so I can remove the downvote and please let me know.

Comment: @arielnmz So, say the lease time of your router's ip hasn't expired and you change to a new ip. What happens if you do `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` ?

Comment: I updated it to explain the situation a little better. I also noticed that my original answer contains "So you can either re-configure the PC's IP default router address manually, or more simply just reboot it." so I'm not sure why @barlop was upset at my answer. Maybe for not explaining how to perform the manual reconfiguration?

Comment: @holdenweb this site is called "superuser" that includes users capable of using a command prompt. If you want to give an answer for those incapable of it, you might want to precede yoru answer saying "best way is via command prompt as that is quickest, but if that is too difficult for somebody, then, restart", -that said- ariel has called into question whether your long winded solution(restarting) is even going to work. And I did give you the reason for my downvote in my comment. The first comment on your post, It was only one sentence long and I was very clear with the reason.

Comment: @barlop it does retrieve dhcp information manually, but not automatically until the lease time expires.

Comment: I maintain that if you change the router's internal IP address to a different network then only a poor router will continue to serve IP addresses from the old pool, either existing addresses from the cache or to new hosts that come along. The correct action would be to invalidate cache entries that no longer belong to the internal network and start serving a new pool from the new network address space. And whatever happens the network interface on clients will need some sort of reset, now adequately covered by the most popular answer.

Comment: @arielnmz ok so it looks like you're saying that ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew work  and rebooting doesn't do a release and renew.  Personally i've never done anything so ridiculous as to restart a machine just to get a new IP so can't comment on whether it would/wouldn't. Why have you?

Comment: Well, if you never do ridiculous things I guess you win, since that appears to be important to you. Just think of me as someone on the Internet who's wrong.

Comment: @holdenweb as I said, the problem is not my router that serves old information but rather my pc that doesn't request new information on reboot.

Comment: @barlop yes I've tried it and no, it doesn't renew it automatically.